# Hide "Authoring information", "Menu Options" and "Publishing Options" in node creation form

Tags: drupal, drupal-6

I want to hide these fieldsets in a Drupal 6 site for some content types (not for all of them), because these options are unnecessary and confusing to the end user.

How can I do this?

Thank you!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[NodeFormCols](http://drupal.org/project/nodeformcols) sounds like the module your after. As well as hiding fieldsets, you can control the order they will appear in, and whether or not they should be collapsed.

As well as that the "[Hide publishing options](https://github.com/nwjlyons/hide-publishing-options)" module allows you to pick which checkboxes to hide within the publishing options fieldset.

Answer (score 3):

If you are talking about when editing a node, this is related to permissions, so those fieldsets will only be displayed according to the user who is editing the node.

If you want to hide them, you could use [`hook_form_alter`](http://api.drupal.org/api/function/hook_form_alter/6) to alter the `$form` array. You have to be careful about this, so it wont be impossible for users to edit the those sections of the node.

Comment: +1 - As long as the goal is to just hide those options from the user to prevent confusion/accidental changes, simply turning them to hidden fields via `hook_form_alter` is a quick way to do it without interfering with the normal form processing. But this will not prevent a malicious user from tampering with the post data itself, so if security restrictions apply as well, more work needs to be done.

Comment: Only a malicious user with access could do this. So it shouldn't be a problem.

Answer (score 2):

Go to Site Building ->Themes ->Select the particular theme and CLICK "Configure" link. You can see various settings, in which you go to Theme-specific settings ->Node Settings ->Author&Date

Make the changes you need and its done!

(This will be easy if we are using a contributed or custom theme)

Answer (score 1):

Check out the [Simplify Node Add](http://drupal.org/project/simplify_node_add) module.